# In what situation can I use ‘that’s not fine’ or other similar phrases instead of ‘that’s fine’when I completely disagree with the questioner?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don’t know what exactly should be the reply to the following situation when I completely disagree with them?would ‘that’s not fine’ be the reply or so?

1. Would you like to make an appointment with Dr Smith on the first of February?
2. I forgot your note book today. I will bring it back tomorrow.
3. I didn’t come in time so as to finish my project.(Supposing that the speaker would completely disagree with the above)

Comment: Using “not” in the way you are considering is dangerous. It can come across as very rude or petulant. A better phrase might be “That doesn’t work for me. Perhaps X instead.” That moves the focus back to you rather than allowing an implication that the asker is somehow at fault.

Answer (score 1):

A negative may be made emphatic by repeating the *same language* to which one is responding with a negative adjective.

> "Is it OK if I pull that tooth, rather than fill it?"
>
> "No, it's *not OK* if you pull that tooth!"

> "I'm sure tomorrow would be fine to turn in that assignment."
>
> "No, tomorrow would *not be fine*; I'll be traveling all day."

**N.B.** Use with caution! It might be appropriate in fictional dialog to express anger, but *not* addressed to a teacher or parent.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you like to make an appointment with Dr Smith on the first of February?

"No that doesn't work ... how about ~~"

saying "that's not fine" here would be inappropriate. It would give the impression that you think the speaker is trying to force you to have an appointment on February 1st against your will.

> I forgot your note book today. I will bring it back tomorrow.
>
> I didn’t come in time so as to finish my project.(Supposing that the speaker would completely disagree with the above)

For both of these, since neither are asking "is that fine" it would be strange for you to reply "that is not fine" (from my American perspective at least.) Saying "that's not okay" sounds more natural to me, but in these conversations more follow up would be expected to explain why you think it is not okay:

"That's not okay, I really need my notebook later today!"
"That's not okay, we need to have your part of the project done before we can do anything else!"